# Java Json enum deserialization

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

JSON enum deserialization is not working.

Interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property="rlType"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class)
})
public interface IA {
}
```

B class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
public enum B implements IA {
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Settings

```
public record Settings(IA rlType, int myint1, int myint2) {}
```

Here is a unit test of how i want to use it:

```
@Test
void testDeserialization() throws Exception {
        String json = """
            {
                "rlType": "X",
                "myint1": 5,
                "myint2": 10
            }
        """;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RateLimiterSettings settings = objectMapper.readValue(json, Settings.class);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not
> resolve subtype of [simple type, class IA]: missing type id property
> 'tlType' (for POJO property 'rlType')  at [Source: (String)"    {
> "rlType": "X",
> "myint1": 5,
> "myint2": 10
> } "; line: 2, column: 19] (through reference chain: Settings["rlType"])

I tried to use `Settings(**B** rlType, int myint1, int myint2)` and it worked but I want to do that with the interface.
What am I missing here?

When I write the object to json string I get:
{"rlType":["B","X"], .. } - why is it array?

Comment: You are using `rlType` in your JSON and `tlType` in your code

Comment: just a typo here.

Comment: Why do you need an empty interface?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile as we found out the interface is necessary, this solution will work:

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property="riType")
    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(B.class) })
    public interface IA {
    }

    public enum B implements IA {
        X,
        Y,
        Z
    }
    
    public record Settings(IA key, int myint1, int myint2)
    {
        
    }
    
    @Test
    void testJson() throws Exception
    {
        String json = """
                {
                "key": ["B", "X"],
                "myint1":"1",
                "myint2":"2"
                }
                """;
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Settings.class));
    }
```

Obviously Jackson uses a different syntax for (de)serializing enum values and ordinary classes. For an enum instance just a `["type", "value"]` is used, for a class instance the full object notation `{ "riType":..., "property":"value", etc. }`.

Comment: shouldn't @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "X")
}) provide it with info which type to use?

Comment: No, with this you just would give your Java enum type B a new name X within your JSON document. Just for interest: Do you really need the interface? There would be no need if you only ever will have the one implementation B.

Comment: I do, I have 3 different enums creating the same classes and controllers.
I want to use an interface instead and remove all this duplication.

Comment: I fear if you rely on Jackson default mechanisms there is no way to evade a type/value combination. Just imagine non unique value names on two of your enums. Just an idea: create an enum with each value pointing to an IA instance and use this as the key for your settings. The downside is that you have to keep track of new values.

Comment: was able to do it with a deserializer :)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve that with a JsonDeserializer.

```
public class IADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<IA> {

    @Override
    public IA deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String typeName = p.getValueAsString();

        // Try to match with the first enum
        try {
            return B.valueOf(typeName);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Ignored
        }

        // Try to match with the second enum
        try {
            return C.valueOf(typeName);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Ignored
        }

        // Handle case where the value doesn't match any known enum
        throw new IOException("Invalid rlType value: " + typeName);
    }
}
```

And

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = IADeserializer.class)
    public interface IRateLimiterType {
}
```

Comment: This is a solution. But be aware that if you have two values with the same name on your enums, you may not get the expected result. I would write a unit test to check this.

Comment: ya, this is an issue. but I will have it with any other deserialization solution in this case.
too bad there is no easy way to do that with annotations.